# Interviewer - I will not repeat the question so be careful. How to print all the text (All) of a php file as written within it?

Tags: php

> Yesterday I went for a php Interview and interviewer just asked me one question,

After introducing himself
**Interviewer** - **I will not repeat my first and last question so be careful. How to print all the text ( All ) of a php file as coded within it ?**

**What I answered-** I tried to answer it by telling the interviewer that I will write the whole code in `<code><?php ?></code>` tag, thats what I could think of at that time.

**Interviewer** - **Are you sure !**

I didnt replied.
**Interviewer** - **Thanks you** (unsatisfied facial expression)

and guess I was not selected. I googled for it also asked it to my friends but I didnt got the answer.
Can anyone answer it.
**Please Please.Please.** I want to know the answer.

Thanks to interviewer he gave me good question to ask on **SO**

Comment: did you try your answer from home?

Comment: An entire interview was based on this question? Seriously? Wow. You probably don't wish to work there anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
echo "</pre>";
```

This will get the name of the file we are in grab the contents of it and then display it on the page as written.

Comment: what about the last ) ending htmlentities ;P

Comment: @Lawrence, what are you talking about, it's there ;)  Nice catch.

Comment: i needed to do it like this echo htmlentities(file_get_contents('.'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); as php_self returns /scriptname.php not ./scriptname thats why i used SCRIPT_FILENAME lol

Comment: @Lawrence, yes the '.' at the beginning is necessary if you aren't running it from your main webserver directory.  SCRIPT_FILENAME works too!

Answer (score 3):

I think interviewer was referring to the [highlight_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(__FILE__); ?>
```

This is the most basic answer that satisfies what the interviewer asked.  I would follow up with a clarifying question as to whether they wanted a prettier display.

Answer (score 1):

Access the appropriate item in `$_SERVER` to find out the current script name, then use PHP's file functions to display the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

this is the nicer way

```
echo highlight_string(file_get_contents($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $file = new SplFileObject( __FILE__ );
    $file->fpassthru();
?>
```

Comment: Coincidently I am working with `SplFileObjects` at the moment, and this example roughly (iterating line by line in stead) is in the manual.